# Data Warehouse - Dimension with free text fields

Tags: data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

I am after some advice on the best way to model some data with free text fields. The following is simplified but generally I have a FactIncident table and then a dimension for this called DimPropertyType. There are effectively 3 fields that define the propertytype called Type1, Type2 and Type3 and these each contain one of a possible 20 values. Initially what I wanted to do was to simply have DimPropertype with the following fields:

PropertyTypeKey

Type1

Type2

Type3

However looking at the data for each set of property type options there is an option titled 'Other' and then also an additional set of fields called - Type1OtherText, Type2OtherText and Type3OtherText. I have looked through the data and about 80% of each of those fields have been set to 'Other' with the respective free text set. Speaking to the business analysts they do some searches that use these fields as constraints so they need to be in there somewhere.

Does anyone have any advice on the best way of dealing with this situation? Looking through the data this issue occurs in a number of different dimensions so I am going to have to deal with this a number of times.

Thanks.

Comment: My suggestion is to treat the free text values like the predefined ones and put them into the same column. Make sure not to create duplicates.

Comment: Thanks Marek, I think I might end up doing something similar to this. I suppose the only thing you lose is the ability to easily check which entries are user generated and which were pre-defined. I'm going to do some further analysis to find out how many distinct values there are in the other text fields.

Comment: Just add an appropriate attribute (flag) to the dimension.